# In Java how can I validate values in a exception with JUnit 4?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

If I only want to test type and message, I could use this:

```
@Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void test(){
    exception.expect(anyException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("Expected Message");
    //your code expecting to throw an exception
}
```

But if I want to test other property, I didn't find a way different that below:

```
try{ 
    //your code expecting to throw an exception
    fail("Failed to assert :No exception thrown");
} catch(anyException ex){
    assertNotNull("Failed to assert", ex.getMessage()) 
    assertEquals("Failed to assert", "Expected Message", ex.getMessage());
    assertEquals("Failed to assert getter", expectedGetterValue , ex.getAnyCustomGetter());
}
```

is there a better way?

Comment: Expecting to catch an Exception in production code is generally frowned upon, but as this is a unit test, I don't see anything wrong with the approach in your second snippet.

Comment: All variants are written down, with good examples for junit4 on their github wiki https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/exception-testing

Answer (score 1):

```
ExpectedException.expect(Matcher<?> matcher);
```

for example...

```
public class MyExceptionMatcher extends BaseMatcher<AnyException> {

    public static MyExceptionMatcher matchesSomeCriteria(...) {
          return new MyExceptionMatcher (...);
    }

    public MyExceptionMatcher(...) {
    ....
    }

    public boolean matches(Object item) {
      ...implement your matching logic here 
    }

}
```

so that you can do...

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void test(){
    exception.expect(anyException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("Expected Message");
    expection.expect(matchesSomeCriteria(...)); // static import
}
```

Comment: If I use hamcrest hasProperty, shouldn´t it be better than create my own matcher?

Comment: hasProperty tests if the object has a property with the given name, but not the value of this object... Perhaps you meant HasPropertyWithValue? Anyway, yes, you could make that work, too. Personally, I like custom matchers since they allow you to express what the code does much more clearly, but that's also a matter of taste.